# Teamsite websphere commerce integration

Tags: content-management-system, websphere-commerce, teamsite

Is there any high level document related integrating `Interwoven HP TeamSite` CMS and `IBM WCS 7 Aurora Store`? Or the pros and cons of doing so?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, like to program the cms for a wcs application, so checking here for any docs related to same

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to integrate CMS into WebSphere Commerce.   One is using the dataload tool to monitor an RSS feed (or some other XML type).  Another is to use the CMS punch out capability.    Typically most business partners and IBM team have assets for this integration.  I would contact them.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any high level document but there are pdfs in which I think you will be able to find your solutions.
These are the pdf's and list of keywords you should refer:

1. TeamSite_Aura-mart_TechNote_en.pdf
2. TeamSite_AdminGuide_en.pdf
3. Keywords : "Clusters or Microsoft clusters in Teamsite" OR "WCM Architecture"

Hope this is helpful!